# COMMIT after EXPLAIN ANALYZE of a read-only query

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, what effect could produce issuing a `COMMIT` after executing an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` with a read-only query?

Answer (score 1):

It will result in either a

> WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress

or committing a previously started transaction (done by the `BEGIN;` command or a version of it), which might have included some non-readonly statements, too.

Before running the `COMMIT;`, you can check if you are in an open transaction from an other connection, issuing

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE usename = 'your_user';
```

You'll get (at least) two rows, one reporting exactly this query, and the other your other session.  If the `state` of the latter says `idle in transaction` (on version 9.1+), then you are in an open transaction there.  It is hard to tell what was run there beforehand, but you may be able to scroll back through your previous commands stored in your client's history.